# How to remove User permission on the List

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, rest, custom-list

I created a list using REST API, and I would like to remove all user permission at once using REST API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have break Role Inheritance on list, try below code,

```
 //Create the REST header  
    var headers = {  
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",  
            "X-RequestDigest": jQuery("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()  
    }  

     //Create the REST end point URL  
    var endPointUrl = "http://site/" + "_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false, clearSubscopes=true)";  

    //Issue the REST Call  
    var call = jQuery.ajax({  
          url: endPointUrl,  
          type: "POST",  
          headers: headers,  
          dataType: 'json',success: function (data) {  
               alert(‘Inheritance Broken Successfully !');  

            },  
            error: function (error) {  
                alert(JSON.stringify(error));  
            }  
        });
```

Comment: Hi @Vishal,
Thank for the quick reply, 
however after I created a list and I did breakroleinheritance, there are still have some user groups permission on the list, and it is built/generated when i created a List. I would like to create a list without any user permission on it, so that I can easily assign any user group permission by myself. please help. thanks

Comment: make sure that you have set copyRoleAssignments=false. Not true in endpoint url.

Comment: I did using this endpoint below, however, it could not breakroleinheritance        
`https://sample.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/breakroleinheritance(true),copyRoleAssignments(false)`

Comment: Try with //sample.com/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Test')/breakroleinheritance(copyRoleAssignments=false, clearSubscopes=true)

Comment: Thanks @Vishal, it works perfectly and as the way I want it to be.

Comment: You welcome. If this solve your problem then you can accept it  or up vote it :-)